# Как использовать большое количество шаблонов в Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular2

Есть 15 шаблонов, отличающихся только центральной частью с формами, куда записывается информация.

Есть ли возможность использовать эти 15 форм, как `template` в одном компоненте и отображать только необходимый в данный момент?

Если использовать один большой `template` и `ngIf` то получится один огромный файл, так же не хотелось бы использовать 15 компонентов, которые управляют каждый своим шаблоном.

Буду премного благодарен за помощь и наведение в правильное русло)

Comment: _Есть ли возможность использовать эти 15 форм, как template в одном компоненте и отображать только необходимый в данный момент?_ - это описание работы ngIf, или ngSwitch. 15 **разных** компонентов вполне выход, если в них будет **только** отличающаяся часть

Comment: Вот блин, я упустил ngSwitch из внимания. Спасибо за наводку)

Comment: Обычно, как раз независимая часть выносится в отдельный компонент

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз, буду пробовать)